# React Native Updating setState not happening even after delay

Tags: react-native

I am stumped on the below bug or my lack of understanding about why my update to setState is not working.  I read several questions saying setState isn't instant so I inserted some delays but it doesn't seem to change matter.  Why is my setState call at the end not working?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, TextInput, ListItem } from 'react-native';

class SearchFunction extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {  
      data: [],
      value: '',
    };

    this.arrayNew = [
      { name: 'Robert' },
      { name: 'Bryan' },
      { name: 'Vicente' },
      { name: 'Tristan' },
      { name: 'Marie' },
    ];
    
    setTimeout(1000);
    this.setState({data: this.arrayNew}, console.log(this.state));
    setTimeout(1000);
    console.log(this.state)
  }
```

The above console logs show that data is still [].  Whereas I expected it to be this.arrayNew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `setTimeout` takes two parameters: a callback and a time interval. Calling `setTimeout(1000)` doesn't do anything
2. `this.setState` shouldn't be called in the `constructor` -- your state inside the constructor should be set by `this.state =`  like you have above
3. Your syntax for `this.setState` isn't correct -- the first parameter is correct (the state object), but the second parameter should be a callback function (see my example)

Let's look at an example of a working function with some different places that print the state:

```
class SearchFunction extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {  
      data: [],
      value: '',
    };

    console.log("Initial state:")
    console.log(this.state)

    this.arrayNew = [
      { name: 'Robert' },
      { name: 'Bryan' },
      { name: 'Vicente' },
      { name: 'Tristan' },
      { name: 'Marie' },
    ];
    
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.setState({data: this.arrayNew}, () => {
        console.log("Newly set state:")
        console.log(this.state)
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <View/>;
  }
}
```

Snack example: https://snack.expo.io/4kVsJHJ0d

1. After the initial `this.state =`  you can see the state is empty
2. `setTimeout` with a callback function and an interval of 1 second
3. In the callback function, the state is set with the correct syntax of `this.setState` with an arrow function as the callback. You can see that after it runs, it calls its own callback function, which prints the updated state.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't actually want a timeout but just did one bc I saw some SO posts where it said that setState wasn't synchronous.  So I tried to change your example on that line to the following which doesn't seem to work     `this.setState({data: this.arrayNew}, () => {
        console.log("Newly set state that doesn't seem to work:")
        console.log(this.state)
    });`

Comment: But are you trying to do that in the constructor? See my note about why that doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, in your snack you're trying to set it in the constructor. Again, see my note -- in the constructor, just use `this.state = `

Comment: ok, I guess then I need to move the this.state command after the array in invoked, which I thought was bad style.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to move the setState command to after the constructor. It isn't in a method, just immediately after the constructor is closed and I get an error about the "this" and when I delete that then I get an error about an unexpected token.

Comment: Right, because then it isn't in a method. It should be in a method of some sort -- it can't just exist at the top level of the class.

Comment: oh ok thanks.  So to recap, setState cannot be in the top level of a class and it cannot be called in the constructor without some kind of wrapper like setTimout.  Is that correct?

Comment: When you said it shouldn't be called in the constructor, I didn't realize that meant it cannot be.

Comment: You are correct. `setState` (or anything else) can't be called at the top level -- that's where properties and methods are defined, but code isn't executed there.

Comment: Thanks! Does something also prevent setState from being called in the constructor?

Comment: Apparently so, although I don’t know the specifics of why.